# How to set step for wxSlider when clicking with mouse?

Tags: c++, slider, wxwidgets

I am trying to set some kind of step size on the wxSlider. When I click in front or behind the slider tick it just moves on too big steps.

I tried to call wxSlider::SetTickFreq(), but it seems that it only draws more/less line ticks and does not alter the step size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void wxSlider::SetLineSize(int  lineSize)`